# How to sort and update a column in pandas dataframe. In a updated dataframe i want to concat new dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting

1. I want to sort a column of pandas DataFrame.
2. not just sorting but want to return a dataframe with sorted column.
3. in a sorted and updated DataFrame I want to concat a single column DataFrame.

---

```
students = {'name': ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5', 's6', 's7', 's8', 's9', 's10']}    
marks = {'grade': [45, 78, 12, 14, 48, 43, 47, 98, 35, 80]}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(students)    
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(marks)    
df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1)

df_25to_75 = df    
df_25to_75.sort_values(['Marks'], inplace = True)

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]    
a = pd.concat([df_25to_75, pd.DataFrame({'no.s': lst})], axis = 1)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please review [ask] and include a [mcve], that includes a desired output.

Comment: Do you get any error(s)? What is your expected output? What output do you see?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your DataFrame more simply, then you want `rank`. Feel free to sort in the end if it's necessary, though it's not to get the ranking.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({**students, **marks})
df['no.s'] = df.grade.rank(method='dense').astype(int)

  name  grade  no.s
0   s1     45     5
1   s2     78     8
2   s3     12     1
3   s4     14     2
4   s5     48     7
5   s6     43     4
6   s7     47     6
7   s8     98    10
8   s9     35     3
9  s10     80     9
```

---

Your original issue is that though you `sort` the DataFrame the original index remains bound to the rows. Thus, when you then assign a new Series 1 - 10, it aligns on the original index, not on the row ordering.